# the instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value is already being tracked. when attaching existing entities,

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an error when I want to edit one of my model named category and subcategory while I can add and delete it.

The error is:

> The instance of entity type ' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value ' is already being tracked. when attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.asp.net while using scoped

While I always use scoped for register my repository so no entity is in use. On the other hand my `HeadCategory` works fine.

Here is my program register

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<MainRepository<SubCategory>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<MainRepository<HeadCategory>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<MainRepository<Category>>();
```

And this is my logic class register

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<CategoryLogic>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<SubCategoryLogic>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<HeadCategoryLogic>();
```

and this my `mainRepository`:

```
namespace DataAccessLayer.services
{
    public class MainRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext context;
        private DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

        public MainRepository(AppDbContext context)
        {
           this.context = context;
            _dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public async Task AddItem(TEntity entity)
        {
           await context.AddAsync(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void EditItem(TEntity entity)
        {
            context.Update(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private async Task DeleteItem(TEntity entity)
        {
            context.Remove(entity);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task<bool> DeleteItem(int Id)
        {
            var entity = context.Set<TEntity>().Find(Id);

            if (entity != null)
            {
                await DeleteItem(entity);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>>? where = null)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;

            if (where != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(where);
            }

            return await query.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I use EF Core and ASP.NET Core 7.

Please help

I checked my code but I'm sure no the other entity is in use.

I edit one record of category to be sure is not the problem of my database, and it worked fine

Comment: It would help to see the actual code you are using to try and perform the actual edit scenario that fails..

Comment: Well based on your scenario, description along with the shared code snippet, it would be great if you could share how are consuming this repository or how its been called. However,  the error message indicates that there is an issue with tracking instances of your entity types when updating or attaching entities.

Comment: I  order to resolve this issue, you can make a few changes to your EditItem method in the MainRepository class.Firstly, you should ensure that the entity is not already being tracked by the context before trying to update it. If it's already being tracked, you should update the tracked entity instead of attaching a new one.

Comment: tnks for your advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The instance of entity type ' cannot be tracked because another
> instance with the key value ' is already being tracked. when attaching
> existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given
> key value is attached.asp.net while using scoped

Well based on your scenario, description along with the shared code snippet, the error message indicates that there is an issue with tracking instances of your entity types when updating or attaching entities.

According to the error,  EF Core is attempting to track two separate instances of the same entity with the same primary key within a single DbContext instance. This conflict prevents updates.

In order to fix your issue, you need to refactor your existing code snippet by  Fetching the entity to be edited using AsNoTracking() to avoid conflicts.
Then detach the fetched entity if it's already being tracked. After that, map properties from the updated entity to the detached entity. Finally,  update the detached entity:

Let's have  a look, how we can refactor your existing code in practice:

```
public async Task EditItem(int id, TEntity updatedEntity)
{
   
    var entity = await context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
    if (context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Unchanged)
    {
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }

    context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedEntity);
    context.Update(entity);

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

**Note:** As you can notice, above modification first checks whether the entity is detached or not. If it's detached, it attaches it to the context; otherwise, it detaches it and then attaches it again. After that, it marks the entity as modified and saves the changes.Please [refer to this official document for few more helpful insight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking).